# Valuation of a company

Tags: equities, finance, valuation, corporate-actions, dcf

Alpha Corp purchases Beta Sub. Alpha Corp finances the purchase price of € 100 million by
raising € 50 million in debt and € 50 million in equity issued by Alpha. The debt is risk free and
the interest rate that the firm pays on its debt is 2%. Alpha Corp has a target capital structure of
0.4 (D/V) and cost of equity of 9%, companies in a comparable industry as Beta Sub have a
target capital structure of 0.6 (D/V) and a cost of equity of 10%. Alpha’s marginal tax rate is
20%.

Assume that the project generates an expected free cash flow of € 6 million in every future
period.

Q:How large is the value of Beta Sub?

I would have used the target capital structure of the compareable firms and the cost of equity of the compareable firms in order to calculate the $r_{wacc}$ of Beta Sub.

$r_{wacc}=0.4*0.+0.6*(1-0.2)*0.6$

Then

$V_{beta}=\frac{6}{r_{wacc}}$
.

Would this be correct?